# Array not printing or going into array?

Tags: java, arrays, random, import

So I have to generate an array (size inputed by User) with a limit of 0-9; but each time I try to

> Array.toString()

it compiles with error. Even when I imported arrays that the compiler states that I can't import or resolve. 
Start

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Frequency
{
  int var1,var2,var3,var4,max,min,var5,var6,var7,var8;
  int [] a;

  Scanner dab = new Scanner(System.in);
  public void rand()
  {
    Random rande = new Random();
    System.out.println("How many Random Values ");
    var1 = dab.nextInt();
    for (int k = 0; k > var1; k++)
    {
      a[k] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
  }
}
```

Tester:

```
public class FrequencyTester
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    Frequency yeet = new Frequency();
    yeet.rand();
    System.out.println("test");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first mistake is in For loop `k` must be  less than `var1`

```
for (int k = 0; k < var1; k++)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Frequency
{
  int var1,var2,var3,var4,max,min,var5,var6,var7,var8;
  int [] a;

  Scanner dab = new Scanner(System.in);
  public void rand()
  {
    Random rande = new Random();
    System.out.println("How many Random Values ");
    var1 = dab.nextInt();
    a=new int[var1];
    for (int k = 0; k < var1; k++)
    {
      a[k] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
  }
}

public class FrequencyTester
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    Frequency yeet = new Frequency();
    yeet.rand();
    System.out.println("test");
  }
}
```